# Slow and jumpy Solution Navigator in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, productivity-power-tools

I'm running Solution Navigator, as an enhanced type of Solution Explorer, from the Productivity Power Tools VS2010 extension, and have been doing so for many months.  Lately however, I notice that the Navigator treeview is often unresponsive and jerky or jumpy, which frequently results in me opening the wrong files for edit etc.

Does anyone else have this problem with Solution Navigator?  Has anyone resolved such a problem?

Comment: The bigger the solution the worse it gets.  I've bugged them several times about it, now I just don't use it anymore.

Comment: Install perfwatson so they know about it!

Comment: same issue here.. i have about 8 projects loaded, and it's jumpy... it also pauses and hangs a while when scrolling. Pity, it's a good way to navigate the solution, I would like to see it fixed.